# Chromeで右クリックイベントを検知したい

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-apps

Chrome App を作成しているのですが、Chrome Dev Editorのようにマウスの右クリックでメニューを表示するような処理をしたいです。
右クリックを検知するにはどのようなイベントハンドリングをすれば良いのでしょうか？

Comment: http://javascript.info/tutorial/mouse-events#getting-the-button-info-which-button

Answer (score 1):

参考程度ですが
Chrome appに詳しくないので、独自のことはわかりませんが、
普通のjsなら下記のような感じでしょうか?

```
// idがsomethingという要素があるとして
var element = document.getElementById("something");
element.onclick = function (e) {
    if (e.button === 2) {
        // 右クリック時の処理をこの中に書いていく
    }
}
```

参考
[click - Event reference | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click)

Answer (score 0):

自分で調べていて見つけた別解ですが、[contextmenuイベント](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/contextmenu)を処理することで実装できました。

```
var elem = document.querySelector('#targetElement');
elem.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {

  // ブラウザーのデフォルトの右クリックの挙動を阻止する
  e.preventDefault();

  // コンテキストメニューのUIを表すDOM要素をマウスの位置に表示する
  var contextMenu = document.querySelector('#myContextMenu');
  contextMenu.classList.remove('hidden');
  contextMenu.style.left = e.x + 'px';
  contextMenu.style.top = e.y + 'px';

});
```